Why won't simple code get auto-vectorized with SSE and AVX in modern compilers?
I've recently been diving deeper into x86-64 architecture and exploring the capabilities of SSE and AVX. I attempted to write a simple vector addition function like this:
void compute(const float *a, const float *b, float *c) {
    c[0] = a[0] + b[0];
    c[1] = a[1] + b[1];
    c[2] = a[2] + b[2];
    c[3] = a[3] + b[3];
}

Using both gcc and clang, I compiled with the following options:
cc -std=c23 -march=native -O3 -ftree-vectorize main.c

However, when I checked the disassembly, the output wasn’t quite what I expected in terms of vectorization:
compute:
  vmovss xmm0, dword ptr [rdi]
  vaddss xmm0, xmm0, dword ptr [rsi]
  vmovss dword ptr [rdx], xmm0
  vmovss xmm0, dword ptr [rdi + 4]
  vaddss xmm0, xmm0, dword ptr [rsi + 4]
  vmovss dword ptr [rdx + 4], xmm0
  vmovss xmm0, dword ptr [rdi + 8]
  vaddss xmm0, xmm0, dword ptr [rsi + 8]
  vmovss dword ptr [rdx + 8], xmm0
  vmovss xmm0, dword ptr [rdi + 12]
  vaddss xmm0, xmm0, dword ptr [rsi + 12]
  vmovss dword ptr [rdx + 12], xmm0
  ret

This seems like scalar code, processing one element at a time. But when I manually use intrinsics, I get the expected vectorized implementation:
#include <xmmintrin.h>

void compute(const float *a, const float *b, float *c) {
    __m128 va = _mm_loadu_ps(a);
    __m128 vb = _mm_loadu_ps(b);
    __m128 vc = _mm_add_ps(va, vb);
    _mm_storeu_ps(c);
}

As I understand it, modern processors are incredibly powerful, and SSE (introduced in 1999) and AVX (since 2011) are now standard. Yet it seems compilers don't always take full advantage of these instructions automatically, even when I explicitly enable optimizations.
It feels a bit like we've invented teleportation, but people still prefer to cross the Atlantic by boat. Is there a rational reason why modern compilers might be hesitant to generate vectorized code for something as straightforward as this?

As Barmar suggested, 4 elements might not be enough to get the benefit of using vectorization. I tried with the following and get the same deceiving results:
float a[512];
float b[512];
float c[512];

void compute() {  
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 512; i++) 
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}

(On Godbolt, GCC -O3 -march=x86-64-v3 does auto-vectorize this with 256-bit AVX instructions.)

4 elements might not be enough to get the benefit of using vectorization.

For your edit, I do get vaddps on ymm registers.

https://godbolt.org/z/dqWbProbd - With global arrays so GCC knows they don't overlap, it does auto-vectorize.  With SSE for baseline x86-64 (and can align them enough to avoid needing movups, with YMM for -march=x86-64-v3.

An alternative to global arrays is to put the floats in a struct and compute the result in a local struct that is then returned.

Aliasing is the problem here. The compiler cannot know whether a, b and c related memory regions can overlap or not. Compilers will sometimes generate code that checks for overlap at run-time and chooses a vectorized or scalar loop.  But here with tiny arrays it's not worth the overhead of checking: it would make the function slower.1
The restrict keyword is meant to address this issue. Here is an example working on all mainstream compilers:
void compute(const float * a, const float * b, float * restrict c)
{
    c[0] = a[0] + b[0];
    c[1] = a[1] + b[1];
    c[2] = a[2] + b[2];
    c[3] = a[3] + b[3];
}

Note restrict can also be applied to a and b, but this is not needed here, as pointed out by chtz in comments. For more information about that, please read this related post.

The provided code with global arrays does generate SIMD assembly code on Godbolt. Note the GCC code is not unrolled but this is another problem (which can be addressed with directives like #pragma GCC unroll(4)).

Footnote 1: Actually, when written as a loop instead of manually unrolled, GCC14 is very eager to vectorize with an overlap check, even for only 4 floats (1 vector) even with just -O2 -ftree-vectorize.    Godbolt.  Clang 19's threshold is 25 floats at -O2, but unfortunately at -O3 it's willing to fully unroll scalar up to 49 floats, only check+vectorizing at 50 with the default -mtune=generic.  So GCC's cost / benefit heuristics must weight loop vectorization a lot higher even than combining loose statements into a vector operation, even for very small loop counts.
Realistically it's probably only worth it to check for overlap and vectorize with maybe 12 or 16 elements (assuming that non-overlap is the typical case and predicts well), if the code can't or didn't use restrict to promise non-overlap.  Unless later code will do vector loads from the result, which could lead to store-forwarding stalls if we did scalar stores, giving more benefits to vectorizing even 4 or 8 elements.

With my edit, I set a,b,c as global variables to avoid aliasing issues, but I get the same results.

Did you try void compute(const float *restrict a, const float *restrict b, float *restrict c) {?

@nowox Using globals does not prevent aliasing issues. However, using (fixed-size) arrays do solve the problem; see on GoldBolt.

because they are well pipelined (as opposed to vectorized ones) - You're just talking about one run of this function that would only need one vector operation so there's nothing to pipeline?  (Except wrt. surrounding code which will of course exist).  It looks very misleading though, like you're saying that vaddps xmm or ymm might have worse throughput than vaddss, which is not the case on any CPU with AVX (except Bulldozer / Zen 1 / E-cores for XMM vectors vs. YMM, but 128-bit vectors are still 4x better FP throughput than scalar there since they have the same instruction throughput.)

@PeterCordes Yes 1 run of the function. We cannot do any assumption on what the calling code does. If the function is called in a loop with no dependencies, then the latency does not matter and the vectorized version will be much faster. My point is that, considering 1 run, the scalar version will generally not be faster, but not so bad compared to the vectorized implementation. It can be equally fast or close to.

@PeterCordes "like you're saying that vaddps xmm or ymm might have worse throughput than vaddss" No. Which sentence let you think about this? I agree with you that the vectorized version should always have a better throughput. My point is about the latency of the instructions which could be higher with the vectorized version regarding the caller code (though the difference should be small if any nowadays on recent x86-64 CPUs). Maybe it just does not worth mentioning this?

My first thought when skimming your answer and seeing Besides, scalar operations are not so bad here because they are well pipelined (as opposed to vectorized ones) was that you're saying that scalar ops pipeline better in general than vector ones, not just in this context.  With branch prediction and so on, there's nearly always surrounding code except on I-cache miss, even if it's not another copy of this code.  A couple vector instructions will take fewer slots in the CPU's pipeline in the front-end and in the ROB/scheduler, allowing better out-of-order exec around it.

Load-use latency is like 1 cycle higher for YMM loads than scalar or XMM on some CPUs, but vaddps ymm latency matches vaddss on all CPUs with AVX, I think, even on Jaguar / Bulldozer / Zen 1 where it's 2 uops for YMM.  If the data was stored with scalar stores then you'd get a store-forwarding stall from a vector load, but if other ops on this array are also vectorized, that's not a problem.

So yeah, I don't think it makes sense to make excuses for scalar code having any redeeming qualities here except if you want to talk about the store-fowarding-stall case if this is called right after non-vectorizable stores to the array.  Then it's a throughput vs. latency tradeoff since SF stalls can still pipeline with fast-path store-forwarding (on Intel at least; I've tested on Skylake) so it's still reasonable in a lot of cases to use SIMD.

Other than a store-forwarding stall, on all mainstream CPUs the c[3] result is going to be ready for a reload sooner with one XMM vector than with four scalar ops.  Scalar has instruction-level parallelism but no x86-64 CPUs have more than two scalar FP add units, or more than three load units and two store units, so you'll have resource conflicts delaying the later (in asm program order) ops from actually executing.  Or maybe in the same cycle if there's an extra cycle of latency doing an XMM load, but unlikely.

@PeterCordes I finally just removed this from the answer since it not very relevant to the question anyway. It makes the answer also simpler :) .

Good, I think that's the best way to go.

@PeterCordes "scalar ops pipeline better in general than vector ones" Ah ok, no, just possibly here and it depends of the calling code too (I was especially thinking about a scalar code in the caller and an overall latency-bound code). But, yes, I agree with you, there is hardly any benefit for the scalar version (except maybe some convoluted corner cases).

GCC, Clang, MSVC and ICX all support __restrict in C++.  If you want maximum portability, you can #define RESTRICT restrict when compiling as C99 or up, #define RESTRICT __restrict on compilers that support it, and #define RESTRICT /**/ otherwise.

Generally, it is sufficient to restrict only the output pointer(s) -- it does not matter if a and b point to overlapping arrays: https://godbolt.org/z/8nnWehnae

Pedantic note: the man's last name (and his site's name) is Godbolt, not GoldBolt :)

@chtz Indeed. Thank you for pointing that out. I edited the answer accordingly.

@hegel5000 Oh, it was a typo mixed with the fact that I wrongly though there was a upper B in the name of the tool. Got it and now fixed! Thank you.

@chtz: No, it is not generally sufficient to restrict just output pointers. See this question. Essentially, writes can happen indirectly through function calls, global variables, constructed addresses etc.

Compilers are very capable of generating overlap-checks, and surprisingly GCC will do so even for a 4-iteration loop that does the same work as the OP's manually-unrolled function.  I added a footnote about that to your answer, and tidied up the wording of the section about that.  Just dropping you a note here to let you know in case any of that isn't what you want your answer to say.


It feels a bit like we've invented teleportation, but people still
prefer to cross the Atlantic by boat. Is there a rational reason why
modern compilers might be hesitant to generate vectorized code for
something as straightforward as this?

Too Many to Choose From
One of the major problems software has had with MMX, SSE, SSE2, AVX, AVX... AVX512 is because there's too many of them! If one want's one's software binaries to be compatible, you use an opcode set for the lowest common denominator (i.e. plain old X64 and its FPU instructions).
Using a Library
Intel did go some way to "automating" use of such extensions with their IPP / MKL libraries. These package up useful routines like FFTs, and the library would work out what implementation applies to the chip the software is running on and uses the best. As a developer, one writes single threaded code around these libraries, and they do all the hardware work of detecting AVX version and multi-threadedness. I think it costs money, which is why no one uses them.
Portability
Another problem is that different architectures do it differently. ARM has its own SIMD instructions.
PowerPC had Altivec, and here actually Motorola (as it was) got things very right. Altivec was fully featured from the get-go, and app developers (on PowerPC Mac, all sorts of high power embedded systems) wrote for Altivec. PS3 was essentially all-Altivec.
Intel's mistake was to "hesitate"; first they did MMX - which was very underfeatured - then SSE, and so forth. Intel deliberately omitted a critical instruction - FMA - from x86/x64 for years. They had it in Itanium, and tried to use its presence there and absence in x86 as a sales point for Itanium. Most used PowerPC instead, and Intel finally caved in in about 2013, and Itanium died shortly thereafter. One of the reasons why Windows 11 has the hardware requirements it does is because MS are desparate to finally use some of these instructions in the operating system.
Anyway, if one want's highly portable C, one doesn't use such instructions directly.
Standardised Libraries
There are libraries beyond IPP/MKL; VSIPL is a standardised library of signal processing routines that is the same on all implementations. You can get it for Intel, Arm, PowerPC and other CPUs (for money), and if you write your C to use VSIPL then you can compile it for most popular CPUs and link it against a VSIPL implementation that knows how to get the very most out the CPU. VSIPL was standardised by the Department of Defense - who have long had a big interest in portable, highly performant code. There are proprietary equivalents - Mercury Computer Systems (for disambiguation: mrcy.com) has SAL, which is a similar idea to VSIPL and pretty good.
The GNU Radio project has spun out a library called VOLK, which is an OSS attempt at a maths library that uses AVX, Arm's equivalent, etc. However, they've made up their own library API, instead of using a standard one like VSIPL.
Net Result
In general, getting good usage of these types of instruction pays big benefits. A big modern ThreadRipper or chunky Xeon running a lot of carefully optimised AVX code (where "optimised" means "getting the caches working well") is a prodigiously powerful number cruncher.
In real world applications they're still a pretty big deal, because CPUs are pretty good at stream processing (data can be being DMA'd into one part of memory by a sensor peripheral, whilst the CPU is continuously processing data already delivered). I have built and delivered such systems featuring large collections of Xeons with Preempt_RT added to Linux, and with careful software structuring had all CPU cores on all the CPUs pegged at 95% utlisation, most of it being all SSE or AVX instructions buried in optimised libraries.
==EDIT==
Compilers, Operating Systems, CPUs
There's a large focus on compilers and autovectorisation in this question that commentators seem keen on. However, as Peter Cordes can attest from this StackOverflow Question there is a whole lot more to "performance" (the motivation for autovectorisation) than just writing code that the compiler can hopefully autovectorise.
The answer to that question, given by Maxim Egorushkin, was basically that the use of AVX instructions kicked the CPU down to a lower clock rate for thermal protection reasons, for too little work done using AVX.
OS context switch time matters too; see this PDF from Intel on linuxfoundation.org). If a process uses more CPU registers (such as AVX's), the process context is larger (obviously). A compiler achieving autovectorisation for a section of code forces the OS that's running it to save more context on preemption, displacing application data from L1 cache. With the context being 2,560 bytes it's 7.8% of a 32k L1 cache, per process. That's not insignificant.
Really, on modern CPUs, vectorised code makes sense only if one is doing a decent amount of work in the SIMD unit. Turning on autovectorisation does not inevitably achieve that (especially in the absence of long loops), can be detrimental to performance in complicated ways, and if distributing a binary one then has compatibility constraints.
That's probably why people don't make as much use of autovectorisation as all that.
That's also why there are libraries such as Intel's IPP/MKL that do understand machine behaviour, and at runtime choose the best approach to a particular function when it's run, guaranteeing an optmised result on every machine. One could emulate that with autovectorisation perhaps, if there were for each basic CPU architecture a -march-all option (and you ended up with a fat binary containing lots of different renderings of the same source).
The Intel library will also auto-thread functions - if it's worthwhile on the hosting CPU for the given input parameters. You can't match that with autovectorisation.
Other libraries (like VSIPL implementations) are coded for a particular op code set and, sometimes, L1/2/3 cache sizes. Such specificity then becomes a constraint on binary portability, but source code remains portabile.

SSE2 is baseline for x86-64.  You (and compilers) can always safely assume that those vector instructions are available when compiling for x86-64.  That's why x86-64 calling conventions use XMM registers to pass and return scalar float and double, and compilers default to SSE2 for scalar FP code-gen, like addsd and addss.  Legacy x87 instructions like fld / fadd are still available, but slower and a worse compiler target since it's a register stack that makes it hard to work with multiple values without needing fxch instructions.

Also, notice that the OP compiled with -march=native which lets the compiler use any extension supported by the CPU on the machine they're compiling on.  So I don't know what question you're answering, but it's not the one you posted this answer under.

@PeterCordes One of the questions in the OP's post, as highlighted by the quote now added at the top.

None of your post makes sense as an answer to why compilers don't auto-vectorize that function (when compiling for x86-64 with or without -march=native).  Compilers do know which SIMD ISAs are supported for the current target, and baseline x86-64 includes SSE2.  Baseline AArch64 includes ASIMD.  Depending on CPU, 32-bit ARM has NEON very widely available.  "Too many too choose from" is a reason it's inconvenient to manually vectorize with intriniscs.  Compiler devs have put in the effort to make their compilers auto-vectorize simple vertical code well for all targets with SIMD.

https://godbolt.org/z/dxvqdr6Kr shows x86-64 GCC with just -O3 even auto-vectorizing exactly the same work as the OP's code when written as a loop with 4 iterations.  (With a check for overlap first.)  So clearly GCC and Clang have zero problem knowing that SSE2 is available.  And the existence of library functions is totally irrelevant for this.  No tricky math operations like log, just plain addition.  And it's purely vertical (no shuffling within vectors) and not even a reduction.

With the last edit, you've now you've gone from off-topic to wrong.  Scattered 512-bit instructions are bad, full-width AVX-512 vectors are only worth using if you use it fairly intensively.  But that's not the case for 128-bit vectors, or even for 256-bit.  You're not going to avoid dirtying the XMM registers; glibc memchr / strlen / etc. already do that, and so does scalar float/double!  And for functions that use YMM (256-bit) registers, the compiler will run vzeroupper before returning (and before calling unknown functions), so that state gets cleaned promptly.

Even if you context-switch every millisecond, that's still once per 4 million clock cycles (on a 4GHz CPU), and it takes a lot less time than that for L1d pollution to settle down and be repopulated with good data.  An extra 256 bytes from having the upper halves of YMM reg saved or not is trivial given how rarely it happens, and using XMM registers for vectors instead of scalar doesn't cost anything extra.

Also note that the turbo penalties from 512-bit vectors are a lot lower in current CPUs than they were in first-gen Skylake-X which that linked question talked about.  https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/102047 . (And again, the turbo penalties are much smaller for 256-bit vectors which glibc memcpy / memchr / etc. already uses, and non-existent for 128-bit vectors on any CPU.)
